# Как вывести на js/jQuery запрещенные регулярным выражением символы встретившиеся в проверяемой строке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var pattern = /^(?!.*\{.*$)(?!.*\}.*$)(?!.*\[.*$)(?!.*\].*$)(?!.*script.*$)(?!.*<a href.*$)(?!&$)(?!.*<.*$)(?!.*>.*$)(.*)$/g; //запрещенные символы    

var str = $("#title"); // Заголовок сообщения

if (str.val().search(pattern) != 0){
  // Вывожу сообщение .......
  // нужно вывести в этом сообщении какие именно символы,
  // запрещенные регуляркой, попались в проверяемой строке
}
```

Как определить и вывести какие именно символы из регулярки встретились в строке?

Comment: а что конкретно проверяет pattern? sidenote: search возвращает индекс вхождения, поэтому  в пример может быть опечатка и вместо `!= 0` должно было быть `!= -1`

Comment: с != -1 не работает

Comment: приведи пример входной строки, которую ты проверяешь и ожидаемый результат. Опиши что конкретно проверяет pattern

Comment: Проверяю на запрещенные символы и набор символов : *{*
*}*
*[*
*]*
*script*
*<a href*
&
*<*
*>*  Входная строка, например: "тестовая строка <br>" или "тестовая строка []". Так как встретились запрещенные символы, то выводится сообщение, мне нужно вставить в это сообщение какие именно символы встретились

Comment: вот так наверное правильно будет  `== -1`

Comment: Однако меня не это интересует, а как вывести какие запрещенные символы встретились во входящей строке, например, если встретились запрещенные символы, то выводить их в сообщении через запятую, например так: `"в строке следующие запрещенные символы: [,],<,> "`

Comment: судя по всему поможет только второе регулярное выражение, которое будет захватывать запрещенные символы, тогда метода `match` вернет то, что ты хочешь

Comment: А надо не проверять, а выводить по-человечески.

Comment: Не проверять это как? у меня проверка для цели вывода определенного сообщения, то есть если условие совпадает. выводить одно сообщение, если не совпадает - другое. А выводить по человечески это как? Пример можно? Если бы я знал как это сделать, я бы вопрос не задавал. Я только учусь.

Comment: Не проверять это как? у меня проверка для цели вывода определенного сообщения, то есть если условие совпадает, выводить сообщение №1, если другое условие - сообщение№2, иначе выводить сообщение №3. А выводить по человечески это как? Пример можно? Если бы я знал как это сделать, я бы вопрос не задавал. Я только учусь.

Comment: @ozoro, учтите, что если пишете комментарий к своему собственному вопросу, то ставьте @<имя>, чтобы упомянуть тех, к кому Вы обращаетесь. Без этого они могут увидеть Ваш новый комментарий только случайно. По умолчанию, нотификация о комментарии идёт только автору комментируемого вопроса/ответа

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov, понял, уже так и сделал в предыдущем сообщении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инвертируйте логику, используйте `Positive Lookahead` и несколько упростите регекс:

```
var pattern = /(?=(\{))|(?=(\}))|(?=(\[))/g; //запрещенные символы
```

Я не делал для всех Ваших вариантов, общая идея, надеюсь, понятна. При срабатывании, данный регекс покажет все запрещенные символы и их смещения.

### Добавление

Ровно было на бумаге...

Обвязка для вывода совпадений:

```js
var pattern = /(?:(?=(\{))|(?=(\}))|(?=(\[))|(?=(\]))|(?=(script)))/g; //запрещенные символы
var str = '{ test } [script] {} test123';

//Сохраняем плохие блоки в виде набора, чтобы избежать дублирования
var matches = new Set();
while ((match = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
  //Каждый раз срабатывает только одна часть шаблона,
  //Поэтому мы можем сделать join, чтобы её получить
  matches.add(match.join(''));
  //Из-за lookahead регекс срабатывает без увеличения LastIndex
  //Чтобы избежать бесконечного цикла, увеличиваем lastIndex вручную
  pattern.lastIndex++; 
}

//Если набор пустой, то в строке не содержится запрещённых символов
if (matches.size) {
  //Преобразуем набор в список и
  //объединяем элементы списка в строку через пробел
  var wrongs = [...matches].join(' ');
  console.log('Wrong input parts: '+ wrongs);
}
```

### Добавление 2

Сверху было хорошее упражнение для ума. Но чересчур сложное, на мой взгляд.
Сделаем проще:

```js
//запрещенные блоки
var patterns = [
  /\{/,
  /\}/,
  /\[/,
  /\]/,
  /script/
];

var str = '{ test } [script] {} test123';

var matches = [];
for(var i=0; i<patterns.length; i++) {
  var match = str.match(patterns[i]);
  if (match) {
    matches.push(match[0]);
  }
}

//Если список пустой, то в строке не содержится запрещённых символов
if (matches.length) {
  //Объединяем элементы списка в строку через пробел
  var wrongs = matches.join(' ');
  console.log('Wrong input parts: '+ wrongs);
}
```

[Здесь](https://regex101.com/) очень удобный сайт для моделирования таких вещей.

Comment: А теперь проверь на одной строке два раза подряд.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я и сам заметил - циклит если делать по прописанному. А вот сейчас поправил - не циклит

Comment: Т. е. одну букву убрать чтобы исправить не вариант?

Comment: А вообще стоп.. Кажется, я был неправ. Исходный вариант вроде должен был работать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в моем новом варианте, который я сейчас скрыл, работало лучше, но не срабатывало для длинного шаблона, например `script`. Так что регекс я оставил - он правильный. Вот только считывать результаты хитро приходится

Comment: Извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, я новичок. Многого еще не знаю. Как вывести значения в переменную из этого цикла? у меня что-то выдает `07910161819`

Comment: @ozoro Я добавил в ответ

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov, что-то не пойму, здесь все работает, но копирую твой код, вставляю его в файл и ничего не выводится. Може я чего-то не так делаю или не понимаю?

Comment: @ozoro Открываете вашу страничку в Chrome Developers Tools, если используете браузер Chrome, ставите Breakpoints и отлаживаете. Только так

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov, понял, console.log(); - это вывод в консоли, а я смотрел на странице. Не знал, теперь буду знать. Благодарю, и 1-й код работает и 2-й. И еще вопрос, это, я так понимаю, универсальный код, то есть прописал один раз и исповать можно вывод многократно ниже?

Comment: @ozoro Если оформить в виде функции, то можно на вход подавать строку для проверки, а на выходе может быть список запрещенных элементов. Ну и, соответственно, в текущем коде переменную `wrongs` надо определять снаружи блока, чтобы использовать дальше. P.S. Если я Вам помог, обозначьте, пожалуйста, мой ответ как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov, благодарю еще раз. Сергей, не сочти за наглость, можешь написать пример оформление всего этого как функции.

Comment: @ozoro Попробуйте сами, у Вас получится!

Comment: "Sergey Nudnov, попробовал, вроде получилось. Сергей, можешь посмотреть, правильно ли?

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov, подскажи как исправить? ** в IE из за** `...matches` синтаксическая ошибка: `SCRIPT1002: Синтаксическая ошибка`.

Comment: Добавление 1 - это от лукавого. Оно чересчур переусложнено. Используйте код из добавления 2. Если предпочитаете всё же #1, то замените `...` циклом как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732478/9921853)

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov, не сочти за наглость, можешь исправить мою функцию или написать свою на основе добавления #1 работающую в IE. Для тебя это пустяк, а для меня пока дремучий лес. Я хотя бы на сравнениях разберусь что к чему. буду очень признателен. Заранее, благодарю!

Comment: @ozoro До четверга не смогу - я в отъезде только с сотовым - без компьютера

Answer (score 0):

**Sergey Nudnov**, благодарю!
Еще не опробовал твой вариант.

**Уже сделал вот так:**

```
var pattern = /[!\(\)\?\<\>\[\{\}\]]/g; //запрещенные символы    

        var str = "тест{тест1] тест 2 <script>?";

        var result = str.match( pattern );

        document.write( result );
```

Правильно ли это?

Вроде все работает как надо, но в моем паттерне по 1 символу проверка, например **script** или **a href** не работают. То есть состоящие из нескольких символов. Или я ошибаюсь?

Сейчас попробую и твой вариант.

Comment: Мой вариант, с последними исправлениями, с несколько хитрой логикой его обхода - срабатывает правильно и на одиночные, и на более длинные шаблоны

Answer (score 0):

Вот попробовал, вроде получилось. Сергей, можешь посмотреть, правильно ли?

```js
var wrongs = "";

function getForbiddenblocks(){
//Сохраняем плохие блоки в виде набора, чтобы избежать дублирования
var matches = new Set();
while ((match = pattern.exec(value)) !== null) {
  //Каждый раз срабатывает только одна часть шаблона,
  //Поэтому мы можем сделать join, чтобы её получить
  matches.add(match.join(''));
  //Из-за lookahead регекс срабатывает без увеличения LastIndex
  //Чтобы избежать бесконечного цикла, увеличиваем lastIndex вручную
  pattern.lastIndex++; 
}

//Если набор пустой, то в строке не содержится запрещённых символов
if (matches.size) {
  //Преобразуем набор в список и
  //объединяем элементы списка в строку через пробел
  wrongs = [...matches].join(' ');
   
} 

}

var pattern = /(?:(?=(\{))|(?=(\}))|(?=(\[))|(?=(\]))|(?=(script)))/g; //запрещенные символы
var value = '{ test } [script] {} test123';

getForbiddenblocks();


document.write('Запрещенные символы в строке: ' + wrongs);
```