# В IE не работает оператор spread (…). Как адаптировать JS-код для IE или сделать на JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Во всех браузерах работает, а в IE - синтаксическая ошибка.

Подскажите, как адаптировать следующий JS-код для IE или сделать на JQuery?

```js
var wrongs = "";

function getForbiddenblocks(){
//Сохраняем плохие блоки в виде набора, чтобы избежать дублирования
var matches = new Set();
while ((match = pattern.exec(value)) !== null) {
  //Каждый раз срабатывает только одна часть шаблона,
  //Поэтому мы можем сделать join, чтобы её получить
  matches.add(match.join(''));
  //Из-за lookahead регекс срабатывает без увеличения LastIndex
  //Чтобы избежать бесконечного цикла, увеличиваем lastIndex вручную
  pattern.lastIndex++; 
}

//Если набор пустой, то в строке не содержится запрещённых символов
if (matches.size) {
  //Преобразуем набор в список и
  //объединяем элементы списка в строку через пробел
  wrongs = [...matches].join(' ');
   
} 

}

var pattern = /(?:(?=(\{))|(?=(\}))|(?=(\[))|(?=(\]))|(?=(script)))/g; //запрещенные символы
var value = '{ test } [script] {} test123';

getForbiddenblocks();


document.write('Запрещенные символы в строке: ' + wrongs);
```

[@Sergey Nudnov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/328913/sergey-nudnov) подсказал базовый код [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972659/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js-jquery-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F), но чтобы адаптировать к IE он пишет:

> замените `...` циклом как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635230/spread-operator-equivalent-in-ie-javascript/54732478#54732478)

Однако не пойму как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так подойдет? я заменил работу c Set на объект, чтобы избежать проблем с ie. используем ключи объекта, чтобы повторить логику Вашего скрипта, по избежанию дублирования

```js
var wrongs = "";

function getForbiddenblocks(){
  //Сохраняем плохие блоки в виде набора, чтобы избежать дублирования
  var matches = {};
  while ((match = pattern.exec(value)) !== null) {
    //Каждый раз срабатывает только одна часть шаблона,
    //Поэтому мы можем сделать join, чтобы её получить
    matches[match.join('')]=0;
    //Из-за lookahead регекс срабатывает без увеличения LastIndex
    //Чтобы избежать бесконечного цикла, увеличиваем lastIndex вручную
    pattern.lastIndex++; 
  }
  var arr = Object.keys(matches);
  //Если набор пустой, то в строке не содержится запрещённых символов
  if (arr.length) {
    //Преобразуем набор в список и
    //объединяем элементы списка в строку через пробел
    wrongs = arr.join(' ');
  } 
}

var pattern = /(?:(?=(\{))|(?=(\}))|(?=(\[))|(?=(\]))|(?=(script)))/g; //запрещенные символы
var value = '{ test } [script] {} test123';

getForbiddenblocks();


document.write('Запрещенные символы в строке: ' + wrongs);
```

Comment: благодарю, в IE работает, а что именно не то с регуляркой? Я так понимаю, в регулярке запрещенные блоки, в том числе `script`/ можно добавить и другие, например `a href`

Comment: @ozoro не обращайте внимание, это часть сообщения осталась от первой версии, в которой поиск не сработал, в отредактированном сообщении все в порядке

Comment: еще раз благодарю. Подскажи еще `wrongs = arr.join(' ');` надо объявлять без var чтобы сделать глобальной, или лучше все же так: `window.wrongs = arr.join(' ');` а то где-то читал что желательно по последнему варианту делать...

Comment: @ozoro лучше явно указать

Comment: то есть так: `window.wrongs = arr.join(' ');`? Подскажи еще момент не по теме вопроса: Почему твой логин при указании его так `@Stranger in the Q` вообще не отображается?

Comment: под моим сообщением обращение ко мне не нужно, уведомление мне и без этого придет